# Graphic_failure in OCaml

Tags: ocaml

## Here's what I wrote in Ocaml top-level

# #load "graphics.cma";;

# open Graphics;;

# open_graph " 400x600" (* Note the leading space. *);;

***But I got the error***

Exception: Graphics.Graphic_failure "Cannot open display ".

## What I tried

I tried to change the DISPLAY variable of my environnement to :0.0, and the error message becomes "Cannot open display :0.0"

I'm on OSX Capitan V10.11

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess the problem is you don't have any X11 Windows System (as stated here https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201341)

You should install XQuartz : http://www.xquartz.org/

Comment: Hard necro, but if you're using Windows, you will need to install Xming instead of XQuartz.